# Hyperledger Fabric V2.3 Snapshot: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I'm running Fabric v2.3 test network, and I'm trying to take a snapshot of the ledger.
When I run:

```
# peer snapshot submitrequest -c mychannel -b 0 --peerAddress peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/o
rganizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

I obtain:
`Error: failed to retrieve snapshot client: snapshot client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded`

The cli container can connect to peer1. Inspecting the orderer logs, it seems that a connection to 172.19.0.1 (on variable ports) is not successful: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/962477f9bab5f34076add1a3b9f63588

Part of it:

```
2021-10-04 00:31:54.519 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 066 Error reading from 172.19.0.8:53714: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

By inspecting the logs of peer0.org1, it really seems that the problem is the connection with the orderer (in particular the TLS handshake): https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/6adf0c6e702387e4e0edd8de0dcf0a76

Part of it:

```
2021-10-04 00:52:03.595 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO e6d unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.1:52374 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=4.028085ms
2021-10-04 00:52:04.293 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO e6e Server TLS handshake failed in 33.508µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.19.0.8:58532
2021-10-04 00:52:04.419 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO e6f Received block [505] from buffer channel=mychannel
```

No configurations were added to the configtx.yaml regarding the snapshotting feature.
Any ideas on how to run the snapshot command successfully?